# Reading in black and white JPG file as binary C++

Tags: c++, image, binary

I am new to C++ so sorry if I'm asking an easy question. I want to read in an image file (black and white) like the following:

[image to be read into the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHAk0.jpg)

and store the binary 0s and 1s into an int array. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Assuming that you want the image itself and not the compressed data, you need a good library. Your platform may have one or several already. Check your documentation.

Comment: I need to relevant data to make a region quadtree.

Comment: check this http://www.scratchapixel.com/old/lessons/2d-image-processing/reading-and-writing-images-a-simple-image-class/reading-and-writing-images-a-simple-image-class/

Comment: You need a library like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg

Comment: Are you trying to extract the pixels information from the file?  Pixels data may not be in 1s and zeros.  For example, pixels may contain more than one bit (such as gray scale) representation.

Comment: what's the format of your image? is it a bmp for example?

Comment: The image is a black and white image. Yes, I am trying to get the pixels' data. How can I get that data?